# Way of evading repetitive library headers and typedef in makefile

Tags: c++, include

### Backgrounds

Say I have this structure of files:

```
|Makefile
|build
|source
|-FunctionLinker.h
|-main.cpp
|-A.cpp
|-B.cpp
|-C.cpp
```

where I would like to compile using `Makefile` and save the resulting objective files in `build` folder. The contents of these files are as follows:

**Makefile**

```
CXX = g++ -std=c++11
CXXFLAGS = -c -Wall

OBJS = build/main.o build/A.o build/B.o build/C.o
all: Project
Project: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(OBJS)

build/%.o: source/%.cpp
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $<
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "FunctionLinker.h"

int main(){
    Vector ExampleVector = {1,2};
    Matrix ExampleMatrix = {{1,2},{3,4}};

    A(ExampleVector, ExampleMatrix); // which is void
    B(ExampleVector, ExampleMatrix); // which is also void
    VectorMatrix Res = C(ExampleVector, ExampleMatrix); // which returns struct

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
        std::cout << Res.Vector[i] << '\t'
    }
}
```

**A.cpp** (**B.cpp** is almost similar)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<double> Vector;
typedef std::vector<Vector> Matrix;

void A(Matrix& A, Vector& b){
    Some calculations...
}
```

**C.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<double> Vector;
typedef std::vector<Vector> Matrix;

VectorMatrix C(Matrix& A, Vector& b){
    Some calculations...
}
```

**FunctionLinker.h**

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONLINKER.H
#define FUNCTIONLINKER.H

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<double> Vector;
typedef std::vector<Vector> Matrix;

struct VectorMatrix{ 
    Vector Vector;
    Matrix Matrix;
}; // I defined a struct here to allow a function to return multiple types

void A(Matrix A, Vector b);
void B(Matrix A, Vector b);
VectorMatrix C(Matrix A, Vector b);

#endif
```

---

### Problems

So `Makefile` perfectly works, but I doubt if it is the most effective practice. Because the following codes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
```

and

```
typedef std::vector<double> Vector;
typedef std::vector<Vector> Matrix;
```

are quite redundant, so I would like to find a more "succinct" way to do the practice. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: BTW, does `#define FUNCTIONLINKER.H` really work? People usually replace all special symbols with an underscore; i have never seen `#define` identifier with a dot inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of header files is that you can `include` them in each source file which needs some repetitive lines of code. So if you add `#include "FunctionLinker.h"` in all your source files, you can delete your redundant lines of code.

Please note that this has nothing to do with the makefile. The problem and solution are within your c++ code.